# Usar um if com dois selects

Tags: mysql, query

Estou a fazer uma query, na qual a segunda query pode dar "NULL" ou um valor (caso exista dados).

```
SELECT *, (SELECT tb1.image FROM ce_users_images tb1
           WHERE tb1.iduser = users.iduser LIMIT 1) AS tmp1
FROM ce_users users
WHERE users.id_user=4
LIMIT 1
```

Pretendo que se retornar NULL nesta segunda query, me retorne um valor predefinido, senão dá o valor da query.

Tentei usar um IFNULL, mas da-me sempre erro.
Podem ajudar a efectuar isto na query??

Comment: qual seria o valor predefinido ?

Comment: porque no subselect você utiliza `users.iduser` e no select `user.id_user` ??

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `IFFNULL` ou `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT 
    users.*,
    COALESCE(
    (SELECT 
         tb1.image 
     FROM ce_users_images tb1
     WHERE tb1.iduser = users.id_user
     LIMIT 1),'Nenhuma imagem informada') AS tmp1
FROM ce_users users
WHERE users.id_user=4
LIMIT 1
```

um pouco mais sobre a função coalesce: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php

Answer (score 0):

Como você quer que retorne um campo de uma tabela relacionada você pode utilizar JOIN para fazer isto. Neste caso que você necessita que retorne o conteúdo da tabela *ce_users*, independentemente de haver um registro relacionado na tabela de *ce_users_images* o LEFT JOIN funcionaria muito bem.

```
SELECT 
    users.*, IFNULL(images.image,'img_default.jpg')
FROM
    ce_users AS users
        LEFT JOIN
    ce_users_images AS images ON users.iduser = images.iduser
WHERE
    users.id_user = 4
```

Caso exista mais de um registro relacionado na tabela você pode utilizar a cláusulas GROUP BY ou adicionar filtros nas cláusulas WHERE ou ON.

[MySQL JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)